# Should I involve auxiliary verb?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

Sentences:

> 1) Whose dog bites his owner ***OR*** Whose dog **does** bite his owner
>
> 2) Whose dog bites ***OR*** Whose dog **does** bite

Question:

> **Should I involve auxiliary verb 'does'?**

Comment: What is the context? Both can be grammatically correct, but deciding which to use would depend on the context.

Comment: @SteveES I had made these sentences up and was confronted with the problem of using an auxiliary verb. If it's right without, then great and thank you

Comment: In most contexts without "does" is better (see Araucaria Man's answer). You might use "does" to emphasise it being opposite to a "doesn't" or "don't". E.g. "Most dogs don't bite, but watch out when you visit Dave, whose dog does bite."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need an auxiliary verb here. Why not? Well, many teachers and course books will tell you that when the interrogative word is the Subject of the sentence, you do not need to use Subject-auxiliary inversion, and you don't need to insert the auxiliary *DO*.

However, the word *whose* is not the Subject here, but a Determiner within the noun phrase *whose dogs*. The real rule is that if the *wh-* word is the Subject  or ***part of the Subject***, you do not need to use subject auxiliary inversion, and don't need to have an auxiliary. In the Original Poster's examples, the word *whose* is part of the Subject noun phrase *Whose dog*. For this reason we don't need to use the  auxiliary *DO*.